# Crystal Report's Subreport across then down option not working

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a main report with some subreports.[image: snapshot of report]

in that red section is the part which i want `across then down` and that black box is a sub report.
I have already set the properties of sub report's detail section to `across then down` but it isn't working. 
Please help me.

Comment: is the subreport field in the details section?

Comment: Yes. Actually the whole `subreport` is in detail section of main report.

Comment: I mean inside the subreport

Comment: ohh. Sorry. Yes, it is is details section of subreport.

Comment: did you program it in your subreport as well(across then down)? Are those instructions a field iteration?

Comment: Those value in `red fields` are for each item in that `black box`. In my main report, i have inserted my sub report in detail section. (here across then down is not checked). But in my subreport's detail section i have set that across then down option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setup the details to grow across then down 4 in width, so in that way you can have 2 iterations per line. Remove unnecessary space to have more details per page